# how to read json file with pandas?

Tags: python, json, list, pandas, scrapy

I have scraped a website with scrapy and stored the data in a json file.
Link to the json file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6JCr_BzSFMHLURsTGdORmlPX0E/view?usp=sharing

But the json isn't standard json and gives errors:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open("/root/code/itjuzi/itjuzi/investorinfo.json") as file:
...     data = json.load(file)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
**kw)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 3 column 2 - line 3697 column 2 (char 45 - 3661517)
```

Then I tried this:

```
with open('/root/code/itjuzi/itjuzi/investorinfo.json','rb') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
data = map(lambda x: x.decode('unicode_escape'), data)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> print pd
<module 'pandas' from '/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.pyc'>
>>> print df
[3697 rows x 1 columns]
```

Why does this only return 1 column?

How can I standardize the json file and read it with pandas correctly?

Comment: Use the last code i added from the getting the json to extracting the values, accept if it worked

Comment: @SerialDev I don't know why ,but the same errors...... sooo sad . I could read the json file with "with open('/root/code/itjuzi/itjuzi/investorinfo.json','rb') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
data = map(lambda x: x.decode('unicode_escape'), data)"  but only one column

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
import json
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
data = json.load(data_file)
```

This has the advantage of dealing well with large JSON files that do not fit in memory

EDIT:
Your data is not valid JSON.
Delete the following in the first 3 lines and it will validate:

```
[{
    "website": ["\u5341\u65b9\u521b\u6295"]
}]
```

EDIT2[Since you need to access nested values from json]:

You can now also access single values like this:

```
data["one"][0]["id"]  # will return 'value'
data["two"]["id"]    # will return 'value'
data["three"]      # will return 'value'
```

Comment: ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: The file is not valid JSON  `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 3 column 2 (char 45)`

Comment: "ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 510 (char 509)" still the same error to me

Comment: You deleted the `[` just after the `}]` ( your json file should begin with `[` now not `{` , Im sure it will work as I just verified

Comment: Yes. you are right .I just leave the '[' behind . and the same error happened.

Comment: [       
{"service_organization": ["\u76c8\u52a8\u8d44\u672c", "https://www.itjuzi.com/investfirm/214"], "investor_info": ["\u90ce\u9707\uff0c\u76c8\u52a8\u8d44\u672c\u6295\u8d44\u7ecf\u7406\u3002"], "investment_stage": ["\u79cd\u5b50\u5929\u4f7f\u8f6e", "Pre-A\u8f6e"], "investor_link": ["https://www.itjuzi.com/investor/3931"], "address": ["\u6d59\u6c5f", "\u676d\u5dde"], "investor_name": ["\u90ce\u9707"], "investment_field": ["\u4e92\u8054\u7f51", "\u672c\u5730\u751f\u6d3b", "\u7535\u5b50\u5546\u52a1", "O2O"]},

Comment: if use 「pd.read_json("/root/code/itjuzi/itjuzi/investorinfo.json")」read your edited json , will be ok . But the first three row is important too , so how to edited it without deleting?

Answer (score 1):

Try following codes: (you are missing one something)

```
>>> import json
>>> with open("/root/code/itjuzi/itjuzi/investorinfo.json") as file:
 ...     data = json.load(file.read())
```

Comment: I don't know why you got that error. file is not a string.